# How do we accept an edit from user?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits

I can see sometimes that my answers are edited by other users. But when i try to accept the edit, i cannot find a button or any other way. Is the edit accepted automatically by SO?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q:**  **Is the edit accepted automatically by SO?**
**A:** No, the edits are reviewed by the other users who have the necessary reputation for this. And if an edit gets 3 Approve votes. It is approved. If it gets 3 reject votes, it is rejected.

---

If a user with `2K+` reputation edits, it'll automatically approved. The OP can always rollback, approve or reject the edits made to his post. You can check [editing faq](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) for more info.

Comment: So a user can only rollback his post. Accepting is done by people with enough reputation?

Comment: @prince: no, user can rollback as well as reject/approve this edits

Answer (score 2):

Suggested edit for your post will be in review queue. It may be reviewed by you(answerer) and the users with enough reputation(2k). Your post got approved edit before you get noticed on that.

Community user(1 rep) can reject or approve the suggested edit.

Comment: "Community user(1 rep) can reject or approve the suggested edit" isn't exactly true. It shows up as the one doing it, but is the result of someone else's immediate action.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the edit accepted automatically by SO?

Simple answer is No,

The people with reputation more than 2K or the OP can accept or reject the suggested edit. There is an edit link with your post ( question & answer ).

When someone is suggesting an edit, you will get notification and then you can approve or reject it by click on on the `edit` link.